# How to write a condition with *ngFor to check two values

Tags: angular

I am using angular 7

I have got a Stock Array inside my Component as shown above .

```
private stocks:any = [];

 [{
        "scripcode": "M&M",
        "open": "671.95",
        "high": "676.90",
        "low": "661.60",
        "exchange": "NSE"
    }, {
        "scripcode": "DRREDDY",
        "open": "2616.00",
        "high": "2684.00",
        "low": "2603.00",
        "exchange": "NSE"
    }, {
        "scripcode": "GRASIM",
        "open": "722.00",
        "high": "743.60",
        "low": "722.00",
        "exchange": "NSE"
    }
    ]
```

Inside my template class i am displaying it the following way

```
<tbody>
    <tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let el of stocks">
      <th scope="row">{{el.scripcode}}</th>
      <td>{{el.open}}</td>
      <td>{{el.low}}</td>
      <td>{{el.high}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Is it possible to write a condition , In case **the open and low values are same** , then only i need to display the row or else not

Thank you for reading

Comment: "then only i need to display", display low and high cells? If so, `<ng-contianer *ngIf="el.high===el.low"> <td>{{el.high}}</td>
      <td>{{el.low}}</td></ng-container>`?

Comment: What do you need to display if they are the same?
Here is how you check if values are the same `*ngIf="el.high === el.low"`

Comment: If open and low are same then display the table row .or else skip that Stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of *ngIf for something like this looking like so. As you need to use two template binding you can wrap this up using the [ng-container](https://alligator.io/angular/ng-container-element/)

```
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let el of stocks">
    <tr mdbTableCol *ngIf="el.low === el.open">
      <th scope="row">{{el.scripcode}}</th>
      <td>{{el.open}}</td>
      <td>{{el.low}}</td>
      <td>{{el.high}}</td> 
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

This `tr` will then only be displayed if the two are not the same.

Comment: The technique is correct but the condition is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up

Comment: while this is correct, this should not be used for large collections, performance wise. try to filter the collection first and then use ngFor, and combined with OnPush.

Comment: @dince12 - You are welcome but the condition is still incorrect. :-)

Comment: Strict checking the two values, I thought *ngIf displayed on condition being true and would be hidden on false?

Comment: Yes, but his condition is on `open` and `low`.